# How to Change IP address in 30 seconds automatically?

Tags: windows, networking, web-scraping, ip, vpn

I have developed a web scrape software for personal use. Now I need to change my IP address in every 30 seconds for resist block. What is the best way to change IP address in every 30 seconds?

Thank You.

Comment: Parse and rotate proxies (e. g. from free-proxy-list.net)

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy plugins that can help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX system, you can try this:

1. Create an ip.sh file with content below, replacing eth0 by your network interface if necessary and  by the 3 first numbers of your network's IP address (e.g. `192.168.1`)
2. `chmod 700 ip.sh`
3. `./ip.sh` (use `sudo` if you're not using the administrator account)

`ip.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
index=2
while :
do
  ifconfig eth0 <IP>.${index} netmask 255.255.255.0 up
  index=$((index+1))
  if [ "$index" -gt "254" ]; then
    index=2
  fi
  sleep 30
done
```

Comment: Are you sure that the method you presented is not going to alter the route tables ? (Clearing default routes as such) and You should probably be more generic with the netmask you are using... not every subnet has that netmask.

Comment: Using dhclient might be a good option, it sets the routing tables for you. But I suspect a potential configuration change is needed to achieve this.